# How do I add a javascript variable as an argument inside a php block?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps

I'm creating a website that uses google maps in wordpress to display multiple markers, and on the clicking of each marker, it is to retrieve the respective post from the database. I'm trying to add a listener to the marker and want it to get a custom field with a specific post id. I can get this to work not using any variables for the post ID with the following code:

```
for (i=0;i<map.markers.length;i++){
        thepostid = map.markers[i].postID;
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
              $('#article-bottom p').text('<?php echo get_field('sound_description', 59);
        });
    }
```

...but I need to replace the post id (59, in the above example) with the javascript variable I created called 'thepostid'. The only way I can think to do this is to break the php after the first argument and concatenate that with my javascript variable, then end the php block, but I haven't been able to figure out to accomplish this. I tried

```
$('#article-bottom p').text('<?php echo get_field('sound_description',?>' + thepostid + '<?php );?>');
```

...but this did not work.

Any help for my beginning javascript knowledge be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you are not closing your php block in the first code block and closing it twice in the second example

Comment: You have to use AJAX. There's no other way.

Comment: @SergeyVidusov Sergey, since I'm new with this AJAX concept, can you please provide me with a hint as to how to implement this in my example? Thank you for any help, in advance.